# Grok formatting for a custom timestamp

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

```
[04-21 12:57:04]
```

this is the timestamp generated by python written logs.
I hav tried

SYSLOGTIMESTAMP, DATESTAMP_EVENTLOG, DATESTAMP_RFC2822,TIMESTAMP_ISO8601

and many more. Can anyone please provide the correct grok format for this.
If not possible how can i use this as a timestamp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try these Groks:

```
\[(?<timestamp>%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME})\]
```

or

```
\[(?<timestamp>[^\]]+)\]
```

Comment: this just creates a term timestamp with these values. I want to replace @timestamp field of kibana

Comment: use date filter for that:
`date {
    "match" => [ "timestamp", "MM-dd hh:mm:ss"  ]
}`